# Simple formula on $X_n^{(k)} = \sum_{1 \le i_1 < ... < i_k \le n} Y_{i_1} \cdot \dots \cdot Y_{i_k}$ (to show $X_n^{(k)}$ is martingale)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, martingales

Let $$X_n^{(k)} = \sum_{1 \le i_1 < ... < i_k \le n} Y_{i_1} \cdot \dots \cdot Y_{i_k}$$

If I take $k=2$ and $S_n = Y_1 + \dots + Y_n$ I have of course:

$$X_n^{(2)} = \frac{1}{2} (S_n^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2)$$

My question is, is it possible to find simple formula for any $k$ ?

PS

This question is only part of other task. Whole exercise is to show that $X_n^{(k)}$ is martingale if $(Y_i)_{i \ge 1}$ are iid and $EY_i = 0$. So if $k=2$ it is easy, because I have formula on $X_n^{(2)}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** It follows from the independence of the random variables $(Y_i)_i$ that

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_{i_1} \cdots Y_{i_k} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = Y_{i_1} \ldots Y_{i_k}$$

if $i_j \leq n-1$ for all $j=1,\ldots,k$ and

$$\mathbb{E}(Y_{i_1} \cdots Y_{i_k} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = 0$$

whenever there exists $j_0 \in \{1,\ldots,k\}$ such that $i_{j_0} = n$ and $i_j \leq n-1$ for all $j \neq j_0$.

Comment: Why second conditional expectation is equal zero? Unfortunately, I don't know how can me help yours Hint. Maybe yet one?

Comment: $\mathbb{E}(Y_{i_1} \cdots Y_{i_k} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = 0$ because $\mathbb{E}(Y_{i_1} \cdots Y_{i_k} \mid \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) = Y_{i_1} \dots Y_{i_k} \mathbb{E}(Y_n | \mathcal{F}_{n-1}) =  Y_{i_1} \dots Y_{i_k} \mathbb{E}(Y_n) = 0$ because last expected value is equal zero. Am I right?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a rather nice application of the *moments of moments* literature. In particular, let $(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)$ denote a random sample of size $n$ drawn on random variable $Y$, with finite mean $E[Y]$. Then, your sum:

$$X_n^{(k)} = \sum_{1 \le i_1 < ... < i_k \le n} Y_{i_1} \cdot \dots \cdot Y_{i_k} \quad = \quad  \frac{1}{k!}A_{[1^k]}$$

where $A_{[1^k]}$ denotes an elementary example of an augmented symmetric function.

OP asks:

> $$X_n^{(2)} = \frac{1}{2} (S_n^2 - \sum_{i=1}^n Y_i^2)$$
>
> My question is, is it possible to find simple formula for any $k$ ?

The examples you are interested in are known as the elementary symmetric polynomials [ see, for instance, [Newton's Identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) ], and the conversion you desire is to express them into power sums $s_r=\sum _{i=1}^n Y_i^r$. Here, for example, are the first 5 such conversions:

[image]

where I am using the `MonomialToPowerSum` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica*.

But, importantly, there is no real reason to do the conversion here to power sums, and you may be better off representing your problem in terms of augmented symmetrics. In particular, augmented symmetric polynomials have the property, by the so-called *fundamental expectation result*, that:

$$E[X_n^{(k)}] \quad = \quad  \frac{1}{k!} E\big[A_{[1^k]}\big] \quad = \quad \binom{n}{k}\big(E[Y]\big)^k$$

So, for example,

- for $k = 2$:  $E[X_n^{(k)}] = \frac{1}{2} n (n-1)  E[Y]^2$
- for $k = 3$:  $E[X_n^{(k)}] = \frac{1}{6} n (n-1) (n-2)  E[Y]^3$
- for $k = 4$:  $E[X_n^{(k)}] = \frac{1}{24} n (n-1) (n-2)(n-3)  E[Y]^4$
  etc

One can then impose your special case, $E[Y]=0$, as desired.

Comment: The OP is not interested in the expectation of $X_n^{(k)}$, but the conditional expectation - or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What does it mean $E[Y]^2$? It is $E[Y]^2 = (EY_1^2,...,EY_n^2)$ ?

Comment: @Thomas You specify in the question that the $Y_i$ are iid. Thus, $E[Y_1] = E[Y_2] = ... = E[Y_n] = E[Y]$. And, $E[Y]^2 = E[Y]*E[Y]$

Comment: I think @saz is right...

Comment: @Thomas So why do you not follow the hint given in my answer?