# Interpreting a sequence and showing that it is a martingale.

Tags: martingales

I saw that one guy already asked this question, but he did not get an answer and I wasn't able to comment his thread. So, hopefully this is allowed. I am wondering about the following problem:

[The problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042672/interpret-the-following-sequence-x-nk-underset1-leq-i-1-dots-i-k)

How does one interpret that seq. and show that it is a martingale?

Comment: ... "One guy" got an answer there: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1011850/simple-formula-on-x-nk-sum-1-le-i-1-i-k-le-n-y-i-1-cdot

Comment: Thanks, the interpretation of the sequence seems to align with that of my solution.